# "A question with that title already exists" in another language

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits

I'm editing titles. But I can't edit one because there is the same title for another question. Great, a dup! No, this one's java and that one's python. Now I can't edit the title. :(

Can this be disabled, at least for editing?

Simple Workaround: add a space at the end of the title.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense to disallow duplicate titles on new posts but allow them on edits. It's usually pretty straightforward to shift words around so that the title is unique again while keeping its original meaning and clarity. Can you give an example?

Comment: @JasonC You shouldn't *have* to.

Comment: I think you are about to make this more philosophical than it really is. Can you give an example?

Comment: @JasonC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886955/breaking-out-of-nested-loops-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653509/breaking-out-of-nested-loops

Comment: [I told you not to tell anyone about the trick... :/](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2306110#2306110)

Comment: @Unihedron But people neeeed to know.

Comment: @Community you don't need to bump questions two months in a row, especially not when they are tagged with `status-declined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit both the titles and append `in Java` or `in python` appropriately to each of them. It isn't wrong to have language names in titles.

Comment: It'll show up to google and in titles as "Java: Can I foobar in Java?". Also, wastes space and bytes.

Comment: You don't understand how the tag prefixing works, @bjb - trust me, it's always good if you can work it in organically as long as the title isn't *too* long. Try it...

Comment: @bjb No, if a title contains the top tag, it displays the next biggest tag (or none if there's only 1 tag).

Comment: @hichris123 Ok, fine. Didn't know that.

Comment: Still, it says that the other question might be a dup, which is annoying. And even if `in [lang]` *is* a good thing to do, I don't think the edit should be *blocked*.

Comment: @Shog9 So what would be your opinion about [a question like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372715/how-can-i-convert-an-int-to-an-nsstring) I'm on the fence about it.

Comment: What's there to have an opinion about, @hichris123? Probably needs an iphone/ios tag.

Comment: @hichris123: Isn't `NSString` already enough to differentiate it from any other language? (And I don't think it needs an iOS tag, given that the same question and answers make equal sense on OS X. It's already got the Objective-C tag.)

Comment: @Shog9 So to be consistent (based on your comment + the "status-declined"), I should append "in [language]" to most questions?

Comment: Why would you need to, @assylias?

Comment: @Shog9 Either the policy is that the language should be in the title and this question is a non-issue (that is what your comment suggests) - or it is that the language should generally not be in the title and the impossibility to have two questions with the same title is not consistent. Context: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322237/how-do-i-ask-a-question-whose-title-already-exists-but-applies-to-tags-not-rela In practice editors add trailing spaces which shows that the restriction on duplicate titles is at best useless and probably unnecessarily annoying. Just sayin' :-)

Comment: I don't know why you're arguing for this, @assylias, but it is a weak argument. Go write a query to show occurrences of duplicate titles over time if you want to demonstrate that the check is ineffective.