# How do I ask a question whose title already exists, but applies to tags not related to my problem?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I wanted to ask [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36984372/3298787) with the title "Convert String to Enum" about a problem I have with VBA. Once I was ready to submit it, I received this message:

[image: Error message: A question with that title already exists; please be more specific]

The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2351195/3298787) is the same as mine, but only valid for `objective-c`

What is the correct way to handle these situations? I worked around the problem by including "VBA:" in the title, but this is [not seen as a good way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208).

---

This question is related to / already discussed at [“A question with that title already exists” in another language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268582/3298787), but doesn't tell me what I should have done instead.

Comment: Maybe add a bit more context: *In VBA how do I convert a String to its Enum value similar to .valueOf in Java*

Comment: @Braiam Do you believe `Convert String to Enum` to be a bad question title?  I'd disagree because I think `VBA convert string to enum` would be something a lot of programmers will google if they face the same problem. [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648) says I should avoid starting questions with "How do I..." and keep it short

Comment: The warning is specifically telling you to be more specific in your title.  Take its advice.

Comment: @Nijin22 Your question title should be the title of your question, not a Google search query.  Google is smart, it doesn't need an exact match of an SO question title to find it from a search query.

Comment: `Convert string to enum [VBA]` is utterly awful and I will punch a baby if you do that.  `How do I convert a string into its enum equivalent in visual basic for applications?` is a more "organic" way of distinguishing your title by use of the tag, but still makes me slap the baby around a little.

Comment: *"Each time you use an awful title, @Will punch a baby. Save the babies! Write good titiles!"*

Comment: unrelated, but your attempted title is not a question. on stackoverflow, we ask questions. please write a question.

Comment: @Will I strongly encourage you to write an answer, as I feel you have something valuable to contribute. Just leave the baby out please.

Comment: Append an "*, eh?*"

Comment: *"Convert string to enum in VBA"* satisfies everyone, doesn't it?

Comment: @Will Finally! I have the missing mechanism for my startup idea involving punching babies as a service, reachable by HTTP endpoint!

Comment: "Convert String to Enum" is a nice, concise question title. The tags on the question will give the proper language context. Why should it have to be polluted with fluff to make it a proper sentence or question?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Two ways: 1. `"C0nvert" [...]`. 2. Add a space after your title...that's really a bug I think.

Comment: @KevinGuan The first one is not acceptable - it'll be edited out by someone thinking it's a typo. In any case, it looks cheap. Either way, the title is good enough now, and I like the current title better than just 'convert string to enum'.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Did you read your linked meta.stackexchange question '[not seen as a good way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)'?

The solution to your problem is given in the top answer:

> The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are
>   organic to the conversational tone of the title. For example,
>
> > JavaScript, jQuery: When should I use one or the other?
>
> is an example of forcing tags in order to compensate for a lousy title.
>   The title would be much clearer if rewritten thusly:
>
> > Can I use jQuery to foo the bar on the baz, or am I stuck using plain
> >     JavaScript?

So you're welcome to post your own question like this, and if you want, do your part for the community by editing the other question's title to be easier to find. It can be improved - you've demonstrated that yourself :)

Comment: I often use <Question> in <language>, in this case "Convert string to enum in VBA".

Comment: I read the linked rather the other way "XXX in tag" is never a good idea. So there is indeed a problem that tags can be removed from question titles but then questions titles can become used multiple times.

Comment: @Trilarion That's why specific questions are encouraged. If your question is specific and another like it exists, chances are high it's just a duplicate of yours(or vice versa).

Answer (score 9):

Your link [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208) says that it's ok to use tags in the title when they are "organic".

If you can include the terms in a way that is conversational, then do so.

Note that the system is smart enough to avoid having the tag twice in the title for the window, see here for example: [Does VBA have Dictionary Structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915317/does-vba-have-dictionary-structure)

Answer (score 2):

The general notion in the [linked meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) is to keep tags out of the title. The currently accepted and upvoted [answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322239/1536976) cites the exception (the tag being organic to the title) but the linked meta question in general strongly favors titles without tags. That's also why they are frequently edited out.

I would not go for this exception and leave the title of the question without tag because:

- It doesn't need a tag. The tag would not easily be organic here.
- The other question with a tag different tag hasn't the tag in the title either.

Clearly the tags are meant to also specify the content, not only the title. Therefore, it can happen that you might want to have identical titles for questions but with different tags. The system clearly isn't prepared for that.

"Convert String to Enum" is a fine title for your potential question as indicated by the question already existing with that title.

Therefore modify it as slightly as possible. **Like "How to convert a String to an Enum?, "Convert a String to an Enum", "Conversion of Strings to Enums", "String to Enum conversion", ...**

Additionally to that, if we feel that two questions with very similar title and mostly only different tags would somehow be confusing we could add the differing tags to the title in both(!) questions in order to avoid ambiguity. Not sure if this is necessary though.